# Unable to set status on discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

im trying to add a custom status to my bot. I tried many methods, like setPresence, setActivity, setStatus. They all did change something but I never managed to change the little green icon to a "Do not disturb" icon. Tried "idle" and "invisible" too, to no avail. Here's the relevant code:

```
client.user.setStatus("dnb");
client.user.setActivity("work please", { type: "PLAYING", status: "dnb"})
```

.. And here's the result:
[image]

As you can tell, the status did not update. The text changes but the status doesn't, which indicates me that this is not a ratelimit issue.

Thank you!

Comment: its `dnd`, and not `dnb`. Also make sure its inside the ready event. And try to remove the `status` from the `setActivity()` method.

Comment: @Radnerus thanks for the reply. it did not change tho, still the same. as i mentionned i also tried "idle" and others which gave similar results

Comment: Removing `status` from the `setActivity()` method didn't work? or like the answer is given, you need to use `.setPresence()` to change activity and status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you must use [setPresence](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) to set it to idle, dnd etc. The correct usage is:

```js
client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'I am now idle' }, status: 'idle' })
client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'I am now in do-not-disturb' }, status: 'dnd' })
```

Comment: thank you fren. I dont know why but the one in the docs, even copy pasted, didnt work for me. Thanks alot!